# Vector spaces without additive inverses

Tags: abstract-algebra, vector-spaces, axioms, semigroups

I was writing out the axioms of a vector space, in preparation for teaching next week, and I started wondering: Do I actually need to impose that vectors have additive inverses?

To be precise: Let $(F,+,\times,0,1)$ be a field. Let $V$ have a binary operation $+ : V \times V \to V$, another binary operation $\cdot : F \times V \to V$ and an element $\vec{0}$, obeying

- $(V,+, \vec{0})$ is a commutative semigroup.
- $(a+b) \cdot \vec{v} = a \cdot \vec{v} + b \cdot \vec{v}$ and $a \cdot (\vec{v}+\vec{w}) = a \cdot \vec{v} + a \cdot \vec{w}$
- $a \cdot (b \cdot \vec{v}) = (a \times b) \cdot \vec{v}$.

Can we deduce that $(-1) \cdot \vec{v}$ is an additive inverse of $\vec{v}$? Of course, we can immediately write $\vec{v}+(-1) \cdot \vec{v} = (1+(-1)) \cdot \vec{v} = 0 \cdot \vec{v}$, so the question is whether we can deduce that $0 \cdot \vec{v} = \vec{0}$ without using that additive inverses exist.

Comment: Are there any advantages of assuming in the axiom $(V,+,\vec0)$ is a commutative semigroup rather than a commutative group? Are you trying some sort of "minimalism" when giving axioms?

Comment: It would save a line on my slide :). Seriously, in my opinion no. But people enjoy the game of figuring out which axioms are redundant and this seemed like a fun example.

Comment: There is often a lot of randomness in which things are and are not put in axiom lists. For example, commutativity of addition follows from the other ring axioms but is always included anyways. When I define rings for newbies, I put $x \cdot 0 = 0$ on my list of defining properties, but no textbook I know of does this.

Comment: $0+0=0,$  then $(0+0)v= 0v,$  distribute $0v+0v = 0v,$  I guess the desired cancellation requires knowing that $0v$  has an additive inverse. Hmmm.

Comment: @WillJagy Yup, that's the issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer is no, unless I made a mistake. The set $\{\vec{0},\vec{z},\vec{u}\}$ over the field $\mathbb{F}_2 = \{0,1\}$ with the operations

| $+$ | $\vec{0}$ | $\vec{z}$ | $\vec{u}$ |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| $\vec{0}$ | $\vec{0}$ | $\vec{z}$ | $\vec{u}$ |
| $\vec{z}$ | $\vec{z}$ | $\vec{z}$ | $\vec{u}$ |
| $\vec{u}$ | $\vec{u}$ | $\vec{u}$ | $\vec{z}$ |

and

| $\cdot$ | $\vec{0}$ | $\vec{z}$ | $\vec{u}$ |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| $0$ | $\vec{0}$ | $\vec{z}$ | $\vec{z}$ |
| $1$ | $\vec{0}$ | $\vec{z}$ | $\vec{u}$ |

satisfies every axiom in the question, and there is nothing that forces $\vec{z}$ to be equal to $\vec{0}$.

Comment: Ah, nice. The additive semigroup here can be thought of as "adjoining a zero to $\mathbb{Z}/2 \mathbb{Z}$". If $G$ is any semigroup, one can always make another semigroup on $G \sqcup \{ 0 \}$ by declaring $x+0=0+x=x$ and inheriting the usual addition from the rest of $G$. When $G$ already has a zero, the result can be quite confusing ...

Answer (score 0):

In my class, we proved the fact that 0v= 0_v using the fact that an additive inverse exits.
I don't know whether this answers your question, but since you are using this fact to deduce the existence of an additive inverse, I would say this is the reason why you need to have the axiom.
here's the proof:

Let x be a scalar and v a vector in V. Consider the quantity
(x+0)v
Now by the distributive property this is xv+0v
If we do the parentheses first we have xv, and these must be equal.
xv+0v=xv
Now since xv is still a vector, there exists a unique additive inverse denoted -xv. Using the associative and communtative property of +, we have
0v=0_v.  (0_v is the zero vector) for any v in V

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).